# Terraform (AWS) Creating private acl dynamically with looping logics

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, terraform, amazon-vpc, vpc

I am creating a terraform module to automate the creation of VPC, with 1 public and private subnet in every AZ available for the region. I was successfully able to create a NACL for the public subnet allowing 80,443,22 inbound and outbound by getting them as input (map of the rules).

the terraform block for public_acl_rule:

```html
resource "aws_network_acl" "public_acl" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.main_vpc.id
  subnet_ids = aws_subnet.public_subnet[*].id

  tags = {
    Name = "${var.cluster_name}_public_nacl"
    environment = var.cluster_name
  }
}

resource "aws_network_acl_rule" "public_inbound_acl_rule" {
  count = var.create_public_acl && length(aws_subnet.public_subnet) > 0 ? length(var.public_inbound_acl_rules) : 0

  network_acl_id = aws_network_acl.public_acl.id

  egress = false
  protocol = var.public_inbound_acl_rules[count.index]["protocol"]
  rule_action = var.public_inbound_acl_rules[count.index]["rule_action"]
  rule_number = var.public_inbound_acl_rules[count.index]["rule_number"]
  from_port = lookup(var.public_inbound_acl_rules[count.index], "from_port", null)
  to_port = lookup(var.public_inbound_acl_rules[count.index], "to_port", null)
  icmp_code = lookup(var.public_inbound_acl_rules[count.index], "icmp_code", null)
  icmp_type = lookup(var.public_inbound_acl_rules[count.index], "icmp_type", null)
  cidr_block = lookup(var.public_inbound_acl_rules[count.index], "cidr_block", null)

}

resource "aws_network_acl_rule" "public_outbound_acl_rule" {
  count = var.create_public_acl && length(aws_subnet.public_subnet) > 0 ? length(var.public_outbound_acl_rules) : 0

  network_acl_id = aws_network_acl.public_acl.id

  egress = true
  protocol = var.public_outbound_acl_rules[count.index]["protocol"]
  rule_action = var.public_outbound_acl_rules[count.index]["rule_action"]
  rule_number = var.public_outbound_acl_rules[count.index]["rule_number"]
  from_port = lookup(var.public_outbound_acl_rules[count.index], "from_port", null)
  to_port = lookup(var.public_outbound_acl_rules[count.index], "to_port", null)
  icmp_code = lookup(var.public_outbound_acl_rules[count.index], "icmp_code", null)
  icmp_type = lookup(var.public_outbound_acl_rules[count.index], "icmp_type", null)
  cidr_block = lookup(var.public_outbound_acl_rules[count.index], "cidr_block", null)

}
```

I tried the below aws_network_acl with inline blocks to iterate over public_cidr block :

```html
resource "aws_network_acl" "private_acl" { vpc_id = aws_vpc.main_vpc.id subnet_ids = aws_subnet.private_subnet[*].id for_each = aws_subnet.private_subnet ingress { count = length(var.private_inbound_acl_rules) protocol = var.private_inbound_acl_rules[count.index]["protocol"]
rule_action = var.private_inbound_acl_rules[count.index]["rule_action"] rule_number = var.private_inbound_acl_rules[count.index]["rule_number"] from_port = lookup(var.private_inbound_acl_rules[count.index], "from_port", null) to_port = lookup(var.private_inbound_acl_rules[count.index],
"to_port", null) cidr_block = aws_subnet.public_subnet.cidr_block } tags = { Name = "${var.cluster_name}_private_nacl" environment = var.cluster_name } }
```

the cidr_block is asking for a reference for private_inbound_acl_rule as it is mentioned in the count.

Any idea on how to dynamically input the public cidr_block as source and also input the acl rule for private nacl as user input? Is it even possible to achieve it ? Kindly share some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

As of Terraform 0.12 you can use [Dynamic Nested Blocks](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/hashicorp-terraform-0-12-preview-for-and-for-each#dynamic-nested-blocks).

```
locals {
  nacl_rules = [
    { port : 22,   rule_num : 100, cidr : "0.0.0.0/0" },
    { port : 80,   rule_num : 110, cidr : "0.0.0.0/0" },
    { port : 443,  rule_num : 120, cidr : "0.0.0.0/0" }
  ]
}

resource "aws_network_acl" "public_tier" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.my_vpc.id
  subnet_ids = [for s in aws_subnet.public : s.id]

  dynamic "ingress" {
    for_each = [for rule_obj in local.nacl_rules : {
      port       = rule_obj.port
      rule_no    = rule_obj.rule_num
      cidr_block = rule_obj.cidr
    }]
    content {
      protocol   = "tcp"
      rule_no    = ingress.value["rule_no"]
      action     = "allow"
      cidr_block = ingress.value["cidr_block"]
      from_port  = ingress.value["port"]
      to_port    = ingress.value["port"]
    }
  }

  dynamic "egress" {
    for_each = [for rule_obj in local.nacl_rules : {
      port       = rule_obj.port
      rule_no    = rule_obj.rule_num
      cidr_block = rule_obj.cidr
    }]
    content {
      protocol   = "tcp"
      rule_no    = egress.value["rule_no"]
      action     = "allow"
      cidr_block = egress.value["cidr_block"]
      from_port  = egress.value["port"]
      to_port    = egress.value["port"]
    }
  }


  tags = {
    Name = "my-nacl"
  }
}
```

Notice that you might need to add the `egress` block below:

```
  egress{
     protocol   = "tcp"
      rule_no    = 300
      action     = "allow"
      cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
      from_port  = 1024
      to_port    = 65535
  }
```

As mentioned [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/resolve-connection-sg-acl-inbound/):

> To enable the connection to a service running on an instance, the
> associated network ACL must allow both inbound traffic on the port
> that the service is listening on as well as allow outbound traffic
> from ephemeral ports. When a client connects to a server, a random
> port from the ephemeral port range (1024-65535) becomes the client's
> source port.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem i was facing by changing the use case a little bit.
Modification of usecase:

1. To iterate over public cidr_block range to create over NACL rules for the private subnet.
2. To get inputs dynamically if the rule for ssh, db connection needs to be enables and based on the condition to create rules.

I achieved the same through the below code:

```html
## This rule is the enable ssh from public subnet to private subnet##
resource "aws_network_acl_rule" "private_inbound_ssh_rule" {

  network_acl_id = aws_network_acl.private_acl.id
  for_each = var.enable_private_ssh ? toset(aws_subnet.public_subnet[*].cidr_block) : []

  egress = false
  protocol = var.private_inbound_ssh_rules["protocol"]
  rule_action = var.private_inbound_ssh_rules["rule_action"]
  rule_number = var.private_inbound_ssh_rules["rule_number"]+tonumber(substr(each.value, 5, 1))
  from_port = lookup(var.private_inbound_ssh_rules, "from_port", null)
  to_port = lookup(var.private_inbound_ssh_rules, "to_port", null)
  cidr_block = each.value
}


## This rule is the enable db connection from public subnet to private subnet##
resource "aws_network_acl_rule" "private_inbound_mysql_rule" {

  network_acl_id = aws_network_acl.private_acl.id
  for_each = var.enable_private_mysql? toset(aws_subnet.public_subnet[*].cidr_block) : []

  egress = false
  protocol = var.private_inbound_mysql_rules["protocol"]
  rule_action = var.private_inbound_mysql_rules["rule_action"]
  rule_number = var.private_inbound_mysql_rules["rule_number"]+tonumber(substr(each.value,5,1))
  from_port = lookup(var.private_inbound_mysql_rules, "from_port", null)
  to_port = lookup(var.private_inbound_mysql_rules, "to_port", null)
  cidr_block = each.value
}
```

Comment: Hi, nice solution - I have the same issue as you had, but I am not that experienced with TF. could you please share how the variable is structured? because I am struggling with the for_each statement and the ? operator. Thanks